# unset($_COOKIE['name']) vs setcookie in PHP$_

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, unset

I want to know that what is difference between expiring cookies using setcookie with past datetime and using unset($_COOKIE) ? Where the difference is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via HTTP Cookies.

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php).

Therefore, `unset()`ing a member shouldn't affect the actual cookies.

You should always set a date time that has passed to remove cookies.